# Comparing frequency distributions of two samples

Tags: distributions, frequency

Consider the following two samples (numbers are put here for illustration):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& males & females& other \\ 
\hline
\textrm{Sample 1} &  100 & 150 &10\\
\textrm{Sample 2} &  75 & 120 &8\\
\hline
\end{array}
How can I test if the frequency distribution in sample 1 differs from the frequency distribution in sample 2, or put differently, if the proportion of males, females and others differs significantly between the two samples. Also, does it matter if Sample 1 and Sample 2 are obtained through random probability sampling in order to determine this? (both samples are obtained through convenience sampling).

Comment: Use Pearson's chi-square test as explained here: http://www.ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/~stat305/Mar26.pdf.

Comment: Fisher’s exact test is another option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I was wondering about the second part of the question though: can this still be done when the samples were not obtained through random sampling, as I came across some sources stating random sampling was a prerequisite.